# Remove last character from a string

Tags: php

I have a list of country as an array .. i want this array in following format to later return it via ajax :-

"india","usa","uk"  ..

Used following code to get somewhat i was looking for ..

```
foreach($country_list as $country) {
   $countries .= '"'.$country['label'].'",';
}
```

problem is it is giving output like "india","usa","uk", ... i.e with trailing comma .

Tried to remove it with

```
substr_replace($countries, "0", -1);
```

and

```
rtrim($countries, ",");
```

But didnt work ! .. Please help !

Comment: why not use the implode function? Does exactly what you need and also removes the trailing "comma"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592994/remove-last-character-from-string?rq=1

Comment: @zewa666 It's an associative array: `$country['label']`.

Comment: `$countries` is array or string ??

Comment: `rtrim` should have worked!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you're missing to assign the variable back after the trim:

```
$s = '"india","usa","uk",';
$s = rtrim($s, ',');
// prints "india","usa","uk"
print $s;
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://codepad.org/Dh2IbllH)

Answer (score 6):

try this `substr()` or `mb_substr()`

```
substr($string, 0, -1);
mb_substr($string, 0, -1);
```

or check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592994/remove-last-character-from-string)

Comment: see this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592994/remove-last-character-from-string

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using: `str_replace(",", " ", $countries);`

This function should replace each occurence of a comma with a space.

Comment: Why replace with a space?

Comment: i dont want only trailing comma at the end of the string . dont want to omit all commas from it

Answer (score 1):

```
if (strlen($b) > 1){
   $b = substr($b,0, -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `implode` instead:

```
$arr = array();
foreach($country_list as $country)
  array_push($arr, $country['label']);
$comma_separated = implode(",", $arr);
```

Comment: this outputs like  india,usa,uk what i need is  "india","usa","uk" thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$countries = [];
foreach($country_list as $country) {
   $countries[] = $country['label'];
}
$new_array = implode(",", $countries);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. create a variable ($comsep) and initialise it to an empty string.
2. in the foreach loop concatenate the variable ($comsep) at the start of the string.
3. add an extra statement in the foreach loop to set the variable ($comsep) to the value "," - after the concatenation statement.

This will put a comma at the start of each appended string except for the first one. The is no longer a trailing comma to deal with so no need to try trimming it off.

Answer (score 0):

**// Try to use chop() function in php. It helps in removing last character from a string**

```
<?php
    echo '<br>' .$country_name = "'USA','UK','India',";
    echo '<br>' .chop($country_name,",");
    exit;
?>
```

**Output : 'USA','UK','India'**

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($country_list as $country) {
   $countries[] = $country['label'];
}
json_encode($countries);
```