# How to git rid of a comma after using the explode method in php

Tags: php

All I want to do is get the first word from a string, it does work, but how do I get rid of the comma as well, right now I'm getting  name, I want it to to just display the name with no commas or characters after.

```
    <?php $pet_name = $pet->pet_name(); $arr = explode(' ',trim($pet_name));?>
    <h1><?= $arr[0] ?></h1>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592994/remove-last-character-from-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) might be more helpful here than `explode`:

```
<?php 
    $pet_name = $pet->pet_name(); 
    $arr = preg_split('/[ ,]/', $pet_name, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
?>
```

This will treat any sequence of spaces and commas as delimiter when splitting up the name.

```
explode(' ', 'Smith, John'); // ['Smith,', 'John']
explode(' ', 'Smith,John'); // ['Smith,John']
preg_split('/[ ,]/', 'Smith, John', null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // ['Smith', 'John']
preg_split('/[ ,]/', 'Smith,John', null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // ['Smith', 'John']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = str_replace(',','',$arr[0]);
```

str_replace is used to replace the comma with nothing

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways of doing this.

First way. The way I suggest :

```
rtrim($arr[0], ',');
```

Second way. The problem with this is, if the last caracter is not a commas, it will also remove it :

```
substr($arr[0], 0, strlen($arr[0]) - 1);
```

Comment: @Salim I know, that's why I added text to the description. However, if you are 120% sure it's always a commas at the end (like pre-created string or whatelse, it's faster.

Comment: @Salim so what if unexpected shows up if there's no comma? the guy clearly says THERE IS a comma

Comment: Yep - Will be faster then regex and rtrim, I guarantee you. If you are 200% sure there's always a comma at the end, this is the way to go.