# Insert hyphen after every n characters without adding a hyphen at the end

Tags: php, string, delimiter

I'm using `chunk_split()` to add a "-" after every 4th letter, but it also add one at the end of the string, which I don't want, here's the code:

```
function GenerateKey($input)
{
    $generated = strtoupper(md5($input).uniqid());
    echo chunk_split(substr($generated, -24), 4, "-");
}
```

This may not be the most efficient way to generate a serial key. I think it would be better if I used `mt_rand()`, but it'll do for now.

So how would I so it doesn't add a "-" at the end of the string?
Because right now the output looks like this:

> 89E0-1E2E-1875-3F63-6DA1-1532-

Comment: `rtrim($string, '-')`

Comment: Instead of commenting an answer/solution, you could vote to close with [Remove trailing delimiting character from a delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5592994/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the trialing - by rtrim. Try this

```
$str = "89E01E2E18753F636DA11532";
echo rtrim(chunk_split($str,4,"-"), "-");
```

**Output:**

```
89E0-1E2E-1875-3F63-6DA1-1532
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chop off the `-` with [`rtrim():`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

```
echo rtrim(chunk_split(substr($generated, -24), 4, "-"), "-");
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not adding characters which will have to be removed later.

`chunk_split()` and `wordwrap()` will needlessly add a trailing hyphen.

Instead, use a more direct approach by inserting hyphens at the zero-width position after every 4th character which is not the end of the string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/J4MYv))

```
echo preg_replace('/.{4}\K(?!$)/', '-', $yourGeneratedString);

# .{4}      #four characters
# \K        #forget the previously matched characters
# (?!$)     #only qualify the match for replacement (injection) if not the end of the string
```

---

A less direct approach is to explode between each four characters then implode with hyphens. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/FroGZ)

```
echo implode('-', str_split($generated, 4));
```