# Remove last comma from string in while loop

Tags: php

My select query is like this, in group_name i am giving comma but I want to remove comma from last. I already tried with trim but it removes all commas, and I want to remove last comma only.

```
$selctGroup = "SELECT contact_id,group_name FROM contact_group
                       LEFT JOIN `group` ON `group`.`group_id` = `contact_group`.`group_id`
                 WHERE contact_id = ".$row['contact_id'];
 $selctGroupRes = mysql_query($selctGroup);
 while($groupRow = mysql_fetch_array($selctGroupRes))
 {
   echo  $groupRow['group_name'].','; 
 }
```

Comment: try to use `rtrim();`

Comment: Check answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592994/remove-the-last-character-from-string

Comment: yes i am sure  echo rtrim($groupRow['group_name'],','); @panther

Comment: @PrashantBhatt Something wrong with my solution?

Comment: no Sir it's work perfectly @Drakes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of echoing out each line, build up a string to echo at the end. Before that, remove the lingering comma from the end with `rtrim($str,",")`.

```
$str = "";
while($groupRow = mysql_fetch_array($selctGroupRes)) {
   $str .= $groupRow['group_name'].','; 
}
echo rtrim($str,",");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$selctGroup = "SELECT contact_id,group_name FROM contact_group
                       LEFT JOIN `group` ON `group`.`group_id` = `contact_group`.`group_id`
                 WHERE contact_id = ".$row['contact_id'];
 $selctGroupRes = mysql_query($selctGroup);
 $str='';
 while($groupRow = mysql_fetch_array($selctGroupRes))
 {
    if($str=='')
      $str=$groupRow['group_name']; 
    else
       $str.=','.$groupRow['group_name']; 
 }
 echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your data in `array` and using `implode` you can remove last comma

```
while($groupRow = mysql_fetch_array($selctGroupRes))
 {
  $result[] = $groupRow['group_name']; 
 }

echo implode(",", $result);
```

Comment: with this output is like this Test,,Test2,,test 3,,test 4 ,

Comment: dont append comma within loop

Answer (score 0):

Using rtrim().Like below

```
rtrim($groupRow['group_name'])
```

Comment: should be `rtrim($groupRow['group_name'],",");` your code will only remove the white spaces at the right side of the string

Comment: yes after my loop i have to put this code  echo rtrim($str,",");  @Prasad