# How to remove last character (comma when creating a string from an array)?

Tags: php, arrays, string, trim

I am trying to remove last character in the output of this code:

```
$images = "image1,image2,image3";
$images = explode(',', $images);

foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo "'$image',";
}}
```

current output:

```
'image1','image2','image3',
                        //^ See here
```

expected output:

```
'image1','image2','image3'
                        //^ See here
```

Comment: Sorry i updated @Script47

Comment: Looks like a frail attempt at building sort of JSON or a CSV list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just keep it simple and use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), e.g.

```
<?php

    $images = "image1,image2,image3";
    $arr = explode(",", $images);
    echo "'" . implode("','", $arr) . "'";

?>
```

output:

```
'image1','image2','image3'
```

Comment: Personally I think `rtrim` would be simpler, but each to their own.

Comment: Thanks great.. @Script47

Comment: For edit my question and thanks to @Rizier123

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Looks like we don't have enough answers yet. So here's another trivial approach.</sub>

If there's a comma-separated list already, and it just needs quoting, then a silly regex suffices:

```
$images = "image1,image2,image3";
echo preg_replace("~[^,]+~",    "'$0'",   $images);
#                     ↑           ↑
#           anything but commas   ↑
#                            wrap in quotes
```

Which avoids the need to manually loop over things, or postprocess the result.

Comment: I'm missing some unicode arrows in your answer :]

Comment: Oh. You're right. That was highly neglient. :↑

Answer (score 1):

`rtrim($string, ",")` would remove trailing commas. [**rtrim**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

and

`trim($string, ",")` would remove trailing and leading commas. [**trim**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Looking at your code it would be useful in your case to use [**implode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
implode(",", $images)
```

Implode does not put a comma at the end, only between variables

Comment: How? i don't understand.Please add example.. Thanks

Comment: Remove the foreach loop. Just add this: echo(implode(",", $images));

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

When you are looping through the data, add it to a string and then use [PHP's rtrim function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) to remove the ending comma.

```
$images = "image1,image2,image3";
$images = explode(',', $images);

foreach ($images as $image) {
    $string .= "'$image',";
}

echo rtrim($string, ',');
```

**Option 2**

If you really wanted to get into it, you could utilize regular expressions and [PHP preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$images       = "image1,image2,image3";
$patterns     = ['/(^)/', '/($)/', '/,/'];
$replacements = ["'", "'", "','"];

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $images);
```

This would eliminate the need for looping, imploding, exploding, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This will remove the trailing comma from the $string.

`rtrim($string, ",") would remove trailing commas.`

I don't know how to mark this as a duplicate, but here is another that was also marked as a duplicate([Remove the last character from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592994/remove-the-last-character-from-string)).  *answer is from the link I put above*

Comment: The flag link underneath the questions tags, then follow the instructions. I did this one.

Answer (score 1):

To *remove the last character* of a string you can just cut it off using `substr()`:

```
$text = "image,";
echo substr($text, 0, strlen($text) - 1); // "image"
```

It reads everything from the zeroeth character up to the last character *minus one* (i.e. omitting the last character).

If you know what the last character is, such as in `image,` (the comma), then you can just trim it:

```
$text = "image,";
echo rtrim($text, ','); // "image"
```

That will remove all `,` characters from the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can use Implode.

```
$images = "image1,image2,image3";
$images = explode(',', $images);
echo "'".implode("','",$images)."'";
```

the output will be:

```
'image1','image2','image3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest another solution. In my opinion it will be a little clearer:

```
$images = "image1,image2,image3";

$quotified = array_map(
                function($x) {
                    // Add quotes... You can also add trim() here 
                    // ...or do some another 'purifying' things
                    // ...that will be applied to each image list element
                    return "'$x'"; 
                }, 
                explode(',', $images)
            );

$images = implode(",", $quotified);
```