# implode() string, but also append the glue at the end

Tags: php, string, implode

Trying to use the `implode()` function to add a string at the end of each element.

```
$array = array('9898549130', '9898549131', '9898549132');
$attUsers = implode("@txt.att.net,", $array);

print($attUsers);
```

Prints this:

```
9898549130@txt.att.net,9898549131@txt.att.net,9898549132
```

How do I get `implode()` to also append the glue for the last element?

Expected output:

```
9898549130@txt.att.net,9898549131@txt.att.net,9898549132@txt.att.net
                                                      //^^^^^^^^^^^^ See here
```

Comment: implode isn't really the right tool for this job. A foreach with a concatenate would work fine.

Comment: implode joins array elements. it doesn't APPEND to all of them. if you have 3 elements, you get 2 joins, not 3.

Comment: FYI: You can take a quick tour here and get an overview of the site: http://stackoverflow.com/tour (Note: You can accept your own answer if you want)

Comment: thanks for your help Rizier123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an answer from my friend that seemed to provide the simplest solution using a foreach.

```
$array = array ('1112223333', '4445556666', '7778889999');

// Loop over array and add "@att.com" to the end of the phone numbers
foreach ($array as $index => &$phone_number) {
    $array[$index] = $phone_number . '@att.com';
}

// join array with a comma
$attusers = implode(',',$array);  

print($attusers);
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a simpler, better, more efficient way to achieve this using `array_map` and a lambda function:

```
$numbers = ['9898549130', '9898549131', '9898549132'];

$attUsers = implode(
    ',',
    array_map(
        function($number) {
            return($number . '@txt.att.net');
        },
        $numbers
    )
);

print_r($attUsers);
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work, not sure its the best way to do it:

```
$array = array('9898549130', '9898549131', '9898549132');
$attUsers = implode("@txt.att.net,", $array) . "@txt.att.net";
print($attUsers);
```

Comment: I think it is as good as you can get. Another way would be to append the string to each element and then imploding the array by a comma.

Answer (score 2):

Append an empty string to your array before imploding.
But then we have another problem, a trailing comma at the end.
So, [remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5593009/710755).

Input:

```
$array = array('9898549130', '9898549131', '9898549132', '');
$attUsers = implode("@txt.att.net,", $array);
$attUsers = rtrim($attUsers, ",")
```

Output:

```
9898549130@txt.att.net,9898549131@txt.att.net,9898549132@txt.att.net
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = '';
foreach($array as $a) {
    $result = $result . $a . '@txt.att.net,';
}
$result = trim($result,',');
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple solution to achieve this :

```
$i = 1;
$c = count($array);

foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    if ($i++ == $c) {
        $array[$key] .= '@txt.att.net';
    }
}
```